# How to reduce space above and between Site Title and the Navigation, Showcase Theme

Tags: wordpress, whitespace

I am trying to reduce the white space above and between the Site Title and the Navigation. 
It is built in the Showcase Theme by Rich wp.

The url of my website is is www.timnorris.org.uk

I have tried to experiment with similar answered solutions and paste them into my child theme , but no luck ,

Any ideas please ?

many thanks

Tim

some code from the css style sheet below

```
/* Header */
#header {background: #FFFFFF; width: 100%;}
#masthead {padding: 15px 0 15px 0;}
#logo{ margin: 5px 0px 5px 10px; float: left; }
h1#sitetitle{font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif; font-weight:400; text-transform:uppercase;     
color:#3C3535;  margin:0; font-size: 50px;line-height: 46px; text-shadow: 1px 1px #F7F7F7; display:inline;}
p#sitedescription{font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif; color:#3C3535; clear:both;font-size:18px;     
font-weight:bold; margin: 0 0 3px 0; text-shadow: 0 1px #F7F7F7; display:inline;}
.headerright{width:350px;float:right;}
#logo a, #logo a:hover{text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a templet you can do that manually, if its HTML just remove the codes you have between the header and the rest that contain either this 
 or this  &nbsp

Comment: do you mean to edit the header php, sorry real beginner here!

Comment: depend on the language, what is the language of your code ?

Comment: err... I first thought I would need to add some css to the child theme, as I have had some success with that to adapt fonts ect,

Comment: The css is already exist otherwise the page won't look like how it showing,can you post the code ?

Comment: I cant believe it but I think I have done it! by messing with the code pasted above#masthead {padding: 15px 0 15px 0;}

Comment: always have a copy of your code, incase you messed with the code you can replace it with the original one and start over, anyways did it work? did you solve the problem or not yet ?

Comment: Thats great, Please check my answer as the correct answer. and vote to get more reputation, and you are welcome .